# Android Studio : style attribute '@android:attr/attr/...' not found

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

i need your help please !

i import an Eclipse Project to Android Studio 3.0.1 
and when i tried to run the app i got these issues:
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
..............................
[image: here the screen image]
this is my `styles_tabbedstyle.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="Theme.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="@android:attr/actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/TabStyle2</item>


</style>

<style name="TabStyle2" parent="android:Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabText.Inverse">
    <item name="android:textColor">#fff</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_background_textured_tabbedstyle</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_tabbedstyle</item> -->
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_background_textured_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_background_textured_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <!-- <item name="android:icon">@android:color/transparent</item>-->
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.Spinner">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Tabbedstyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Tabbedstyle.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Tabbedstyle</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Tabbedstyle</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

i didn't understand the problem !!

how can i solve this ??